# Кодировка messages.properties в сторонней библиотеке spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Использую в проекте spring boot библиотеку Passay для валидации пароля. В самой библиотеке есть файл messages.properties с описанием ошибок валидации на английском языке. Мне нужно эти сообщения выдать на русском. 
Пробовал менять сам текст сообщений на русский с заменой кодировки файла на utf-8. В spring корректно выдает кириллицу, а на веб-страничке крякозябры в кодировке iso 8859-1.
При этом файлы .properties самого проекта работают нормально с кириллицей.
Посоветуйте способ выведения кириллицы на веб страничке. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил путем добавления кастомного файла локализации из мануалки passay следующим образом:

`Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/messages.properties"));
MessageResolver resolver = new PropertiesMessageResolver(props);
PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator( resolver, new LengthRule(8, 16), new WhitespaceRule());`

Дальше вопросы по кодировке отпадают.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]